# Inno Setup customize FinishedLabel with Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, wizard, pascalscript

My goal with Inno Setup 6.x is to customize the `FinishedLabel` text in code, i.e., Pascal Script. The reason why I'm using Pascal Script is that I want to only customize/change the label if `IsAdminMode()` is true. How can I do that?

The following two approaches do not work:

1. Use a scripted constant:

   ```
   [Messages]
   FinishedLabel={code:GetFinishedLabel}
   ```

   ```pascal
   [Code]
   function GetFinishedLabel(Param: String): String;
   begin
     Result := 'BLA';
   end;
   ```

   This shows "{code:GetFinishedLabel}" rather than "BLA".
2. Customize the wizard in `InitializeWizard`.

   Complete (failing) example:

   ```pascal
   [Code]
   procedure InitializeWizard();
   begin
     WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption := 'BLA';
   end;
   ```

   The `FinishLabel` still shows the original text from `Default.isl`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FinishedLabel` is updated at the end of the installation according to various factors. So your value set in `InitializeWizard` is overridden. You have to set your custom message later, such as in `CurPageChanged(wpFinished)`:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption := 'BLA';
  end;
end;
```

---

You might consider to improve the code to do what Inno Setup would do, like:

- Taking into account, if restart is needed (`FinishedRestartLabel`);
- Taking into account, if icons were created (`FinishedLabel` vs. `FinishedLabelNoIcons`);
- Adjusting the label height to fit the message;
- Shifting `RunList` position according to the message height.